# Override OnResume() method of all activities Android

Tags: android, overriding, android-activity, onresume

I have and app with more than 10 activities and I would like override the method `onResume()` with the same code in all of them.

I know that I can override this method in each activity, but I'm looking for an efficient solution.

Moreover I would like inside this onResume show a message depending what activity is coming from, for example: if you are in the MainActivity I want that this common onResume detects that is coming from this activity and show `I'm coming from MainActivity`

Thank you.

Comment: But, if we extend BaseClass, we cannot extend any other class, so can my solution be the better one?

Comment: @Shrikant No it's not because it does not work. You can define `onResume` there but you can't put any common code in there.

Comment: any other class like what, since anyway you were going to extend Activity?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you should `Override` activity in a `BaseClass` and use your `BaseClass` instead of Activity in the other activities:

```
public class BaseClass extends Activity 
{

  public void onResume() 
  {
    // common code
  } 
}

public class OtherClass extends BaseClass 
{
}
```

Comment: But, if we extend BaseClass, we cannot extend any other class, so can my solution be the better one?

Comment: Why you need to extend other classes? previously you are extending only from activity na??

Comment: @EldhoseMBabu it is OtherClass to extend BaseClasas

Comment: I dont know whether what i understand is wrong...BaseClass is inherited from activity and your other activity classes are inherited from BaseClass.. so it is internally got inherited from activity. Then why you need to inherit further?

Comment: Now I would like inside this onResume show a message depending what activity is coming from, for example: if you are in the MainActivity I want that this common onResume detects that is coming from this activity and show "I'm coming from MainActivity"

Answer (score 0):

Make a parent activity and override its onResume, then make all your 10 activities extend the creted parent..

Comment: Now I would like inside this onResume show a message depending what activity is coming from, for example: if you are in the MainActivity I want that this common onResume detects that is coming from this activity and show "I'm coming from MainActivity"